Topology: Is it possible that, the preimage of a non-open and non-close set is open?
Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map from space $X$ to $Y$. $U\subset Y$ is neither open nor close in Y, is it possible that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$?
I met this problem when I am trying to prove the following proposition:
Let $i:Y\rightarrow X$ be an injective set map between spaces. The following are equivalent:
(1) $i$ is an embedding.
(2) A set map $g:Z\rightarrow Y$ from any topological space $Z$ is continuous if and only
if $ig:Z\rightarrow X$ is continuous.
When I prove (2)→(1), suppose that $g$ is continuous, let $V\subset X$ be an open set. $(ig)^{-1} = g^{-1}(i^{-1}(V))$. There are three cases:

If $i^{-1}(V)$ is open, then $g^{-1}(i^{-1}(V))$ must be open (because $g$ is continuous).
If $i^{-1}(V)$ is close, then $g^{-1}(i^{-1}(V))$ must be close.
If $i^{-1}(V)$ is non-open and non-close, I am not sure what $g^{-1}(i^{-1}(V))$ will be.

So if I can exclude case 3, then $i^{-1}(V)$ must be open. So I can prove that $i$ is continuous.

Hint (for your first question): Consider a map from the topological space with just one point to any topological space $Y$ of your choice.

You cannot exclude case 3, and you do not need to. Assuming (2) and trying to prove that $i$ is continuous, just choose $g={\rm id}_Y$.

To consider the extremely familiar, $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology, $f(x) = x^2$, $f^{-1}([0,1)) = (-1,1)$.

@aschepler: Suggest you make this an answer!

You cannot exclude case 3 (see counterexample below), and you do not need to. Assuming (2) and trying to prove that $i$ is continuous, just choose $g={\rm id}_Y$.
Counterexample: take $f={\rm id}_X:(X,T_1)\to(X,T_2)$ where $T_2$ is the indiscrete topology and $T_1$ the discrete one, and $U=$ any nonempty proper subset of $X$ (assuming $|X|\ge2$).

Thanks for you answer.
